# Is there a faster way I can change multiple elements in an array?

Tags: python, arrays

Suppose currently I have the following array: (Using Python)

```
arr = np.ones(shape=10 , dtype=np.int64)
print(arr)
**output:**
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Now if I want to change the following elements of the array: [2,3,6,7] into the numbers [5,5,2,2], in other words, arr[2] = 5, arr[3] = 5, etc. Is there a faster way I can do that? Thanks:)

Comment: [Integer indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing),  - It works with assignment as well as selection - [https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)

Comment: Does [How does integer-array indexing work in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608710/how-does-integer-array-indexing-work-in-numpy) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
arr[[2,3,6,7]] = [5,5,2,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the Python list answer, for Numpy arrays check comments.

```
indices = [2, 3, 6, 7]
b = [5, 5, 2, 2]
assert len(indices) == len(b)

for r_index, l_index in enumerate(indices):
   a[l_index] = b[r_index]

a # [1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```